# How to store Image taken from camera with a captured date and time in my specified folder?

Tags: java, android, image, filenames, android-camera

I want to store image taken from camera to my specific folder in sd card with captured date and time. 
The code is

```
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if (photo != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        String strCurDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        String imageName = "" + strCurDate + ".jpg";
        Bundle imgData = new Bundle();
        imgData.putString("IMAGENAME", imageName);
```

The problem here is since the date format has space between date and time(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss), i am not able to store the image with the specified date format in sd card.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit: The problem solved. I changed the date format to yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss. The problem was not with the space but ':' since .jpg filename doesn't accept colon.

Comment: Hi @Shrikant and welcome to SO! It's perfectly acceptable here for you to answer your own questions so if you could write up what worked for you and how you solved your problem (as an **answer**), the community would be very grateful! Also, don't forget to **accept** your answer whenever time allows.

Comment: Use this--DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss");
  Date date = new Date();
   String imageName = "" + strCurDate + ".jpg";